# UIView background color in Custom TableView only change when scrolled, why?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change all color of UIView to pink not blue when first load tableview not just when scrolled, how to fix ? what happen now, color just changed when you scroll to bottom the tableview and back to top scroll then change the top blue to pink again

I'm confused for a week for this stuff, haha

[image: image_problem_header_view]

My TableViewCell

```swift
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        containerItem.addViewRounded(cornerRadius: 8)
        containerItem.addShadow()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        containerHeader.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 8)
    }

    func configureCell(exc: Exceptional) {
        containerHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Cinderella")
        lblStatusApprove.textColor = UIColor(named: "Carnation")
    }
```

this is my tableview related code :

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let exc = arrayOfExceptional[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExceptionalTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ExceptionalTableViewCell

        cell.lblApprover.text = exc.approver
        cell.lblCreatedAt.text = exc.createdAt
        cell.lblSubmitDate.text = exc.submitDate
        cell.lblTypeExceptional.text = exc.typeName
        cell.lblExcStartEnd.text = "\(exc.timeStart) - \(exc.timeEnd)"
        cell.lblDescription.text = exc.excDescription

        cell.lblSubmitDate.sizeToFit()
        cell.lblExcStartEnd.sizeToFit()
        cell.lblApprover.sizeToFit()
        cell.lblCreatedAt.sizeToFit()

cell.configureCell(exc: exc)

        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        loadMoreControl.didScroll()
    }
```

My Viewdidload :

```
excTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ExceptionalTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExceptionalTableViewCell")

content and reload table here
```

Comment: General rule, when you `override` native api method like `override func layoutSubviews()`, you should call `super` as `super.layoutSubviews()`. You are not calling `configureCell(exc:` anywhere so is it what you are missing?

Comment: Move all your cell configurations from the ```cellForRowAt``` to the ```configureCell(exc:)``` function inside the cell. And call that method in ```cellForRowAt```

Comment: @kamran, sorry forgot to put the configureCell in cellforrow, i edit my answer,, the defaul color from xib is blue,, i wanna change it to pink, the other bottom cell when you scroll already pink, the first load is always blue

Comment: try putting this line `containerHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Cinderella")` inside `awakeFromNib` and see if it helps.

Comment: @Kamran but i use the cell in 3 different status, tab pending = yellow, approved = blue, and reject = pink("cinderella"),, 1 tab just show 1 color,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys i found the solution to fix my problem, because the cell is not created yet fully in the first load so we need to add "willDisplay cell"

so i add this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = cell as? ExceptionalTableViewCell {
            cell.containerHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Cinderella")
            cell.lblStatusApprove.textColor = UIColor(named: "Carnation")
        }
    }
```